# Add image faster in excel using Interop library

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am simply putting values in Excel and also images to some certain cells. Sample from my code looks like this ;

```
   //sb is a String Builder and gets filled by loop
   xlWorkSheet.Cells[sheetRowPosition, 4] = sb.ToString();
   xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(loadPath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, float.Parse(((left) + 5).ToString()), float.Parse(((top) + 5).ToString()), 60, 60);
```

I have done it simply like looping through a collection and insert data to cells. But it is slow like turtle. So I have changed my mind to refresh my code like this ;

```
private static void WriteArray(int rows, int columns, Worksheet worksheet)
{
        var data = new object[rows, columns];
       for (var row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
       {
           for (var column = 1; column <= columns; column++)
             {
             data[row - 1, column - 1] = "Test";
              }
         }

     var startCell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
       var endCell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[rows, columns];
       var writeRange = worksheet.Range[startCell, endCell];

    writeRange.Value2 = data;
}
```

http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Write-data-to-an-Excel-worksheet-with-C-fast.aspx

But the question is now, how can I insert images to cells using the second method?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that it isn't possible to treat an image as a data object.

Even if you were able to hack it in, I wouldn't trust Excel to support it in future versions.  Instead, I would create an array of objects which is your picture data, then after inserting the data, go through your array of picture data and insert them one at a time.

```
for (i = ROW LOOP)
{
   for (j = COL LOOP)
   {
      if (ISIMAGE)
      {
         ImageArray.ADD(new imageData(i,j,ImageLoc))
      }
      else
      {
         data[i,j] = "Test";
      }
   }
}
writeRange.Value2 = data;
foreach (imageData iData in ImageArray)
{
   //Parse the object and load the picture to the right row/col
}
```

Yeah, you are still dealing with one picture at a time, but I am not convinced you can improve on that.